# switch in another switch case

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

i have some big problem witch switch case in switch. what is a problem.
if i do oprions 1-5(first switch) ever think working. If i use 6.(first) and 10.(second) also working. But If i do: take 1/2/3/4 times 1-5(options) and after 12.(from second menu) and than second time oprion 1-5(from first) program sometimes stop, and sometimes working but puts on screen/file somethink like "-12391239~21312312=3123121"
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct d
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int wynik;
    char znak;
};
int ok;
void wypisz(struct d* tabs)
{
    if(ok==0)
    {
        printf("historia pusta!");
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ok; i++) {
            printf("%d", tabs[i].a);
            printf("%c", tabs[i].znak);
            printf("%d", tabs[i].b);
            printf("=");
            printf("%d", tabs[i].wynik);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
void usunzpliku()
{
    FILE *plik=fopen("siema.txt", "w");
    if(plik)
    {
        fputc('\0', plik);
        printf("WYCZYSZCZONO HISTORIE Z PLIKU\n");
        fclose(plik);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nie udalo sie wczytac pliku.");
    }

}
/*void usun(struct d* tabs)
{
    if(ok==0)
    {
        printf("historia pusta!");
    }
    else
    {
        ok=0;
        tabs = realloc(tabs, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    }
}*/
void zapiszdo(struct d* tabs)
{
    FILE *plik=fopen("siema.txt", "w");

    if(ok==0)
    {
        printf("historia pusta!");
    }
    else
    {
        if(plik)
        {
            printf("\n%d\n",ok);
            for (int i = 0; i < ok; i++) {
                fprintf(plik,"%d", tabs[i].a);
                fprintf(plik,"%c", tabs[i].znak);
                fprintf(plik,"%d", tabs[i].b);
                fprintf(plik, "=");
                fprintf(plik,"%d", tabs[i].wynik);
                fprintf(plik,"\n");
            }
            fclose(plik);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Nie udalo sie wczytac pliku.");
        }
    }
}
void wyswietlz()
{
    FILE *plik=fopen("siema.txt", "r");
    if(plik)
    {
        int c;
        c=getc(plik);
        printf("####    HISTORIA   ####\n");
        while(c!=EOF)
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            c=getc(plik);
        }
        printf("####    KONIEC    ####");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nie udalo sie wczytac pliku.");
    }
    fclose(plik);
}
void dodawanie(int x, int y, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x+y;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = y;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '+';
    printf("\nWYKONUJE SIE\n");
}
void odejmowanie(int x, int y, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x-y;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = y;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '-';
}
void mnozenie(int x, int y, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x*y;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = y;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '*';
}
void dzielenie(int x, int y, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x/y;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = y;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '/';
}
void potegowanie(int x, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x*x;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = 2;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '^';
}
int main()
{
    int A, B;
    int dz;
    struct d *dzi = malloc (ok* sizeof(struct d));
    for(;;)
    {
        printf(" KALKULATOR ");
        printf("[%d]\n", ok);
        printf(" 1. dodwanie \n");
        printf(" 2. odejmowanie \n");
        printf(" 3. mnozenie \n");
        printf(" 4. dzielenie \n");
        printf(" 5. potegowanie \n");
        printf(" 6. historia \n");
        printf(" co chcesz policzyc: ");
        scanf("%d", &dz);
        switch (dz) {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Podaj A: ");
                scanf("%d", &A);
                while (getchar() != '\n')
                    continue;
                printf(" Podaj B: ");
                scanf("%d", &B);
                while (getchar() != '\n')
                    continue;
                dodawanie(A, B, dzi);

            }break;
            case 2:
            {
                printf("Podaj A: ");
                scanf(" %d", &A);
                printf(" Podaj B: ");
                scanf(" %d", &B);
                odejmowanie(A, B, dzi);
            }break;
            case 3:
            {
                printf("Podaj A: ");
                scanf("%d", &A);
                printf(" Podaj B: ");
                scanf("%d", &B);
                mnozenie(A, B, dzi);
            }break;
            case 4:
            {
                printf("Podaj A: ");
                scanf("%d", &A);
                printf(" Podaj B: ");
                scanf("%d", &B);
                dzielenie(A, B, dzi);
            }break;
            case 5:
            {
                printf("Podaj A: ");
                scanf("%d", &A);
                potegowanie(A, dzi);
            }break;
            case 6:
            {
                int h;
                printf(" HISTORIA \n");
                printf(" 10. wypisz. \n");
                printf(" 11. usun. \n");
                printf(" 12. zapisz do pliku \n");
                printf(" 13. wyswietl z pliku \n");
                printf(" 14. usun z pliku \n");
                printf(" co chcesz zrobic z historia: ");
                scanf("%d", &h);
                switch (h)
                {
                    case 10: {
                        wypisz(dzi);
                    }break;
                    case 11: {
                        // usun(dzi);
                    }break;
                    case 12: {
                        zapiszdo(dzi);
                    }break;
                    case 13: {
                        wyswietlz();
                    }break;
                    case 14: {
                        usunzpliku();
                    }break;
                    default: {
                        printf(" nie prawidlowe dzialanie ");
                    }break;
                }
            }break;
            default:
            {
                printf(" Brak dzialania ");
            }break;
        }
    }
}
```

rezult:

```
 KALKULATOR [0]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:1
 Podaj A:2
  Podaj B:2

WYKONUJE SIE
 KALKULATOR [1]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:6
  HISTORIA
 10. wypisz.
 11. usun.
 12. zapisz do pliku
 13. wyswietl z pliku
 14. usun z pliku
 co chcesz zrobic z historia:10
 2+2=4
 KALKULATOR [1]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:2
 Podaj A:2
  Podaj B:2
  KALKULATOR [2]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:6
  HISTORIA
 10. wypisz.
 11. usun.
 12. zapisz do pliku
 13. wyswietl z pliku
 14. usun z pliku
 co chcesz zrobic z historia:10
 2+2=4
2-2=0
 KALKULATOR [2]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:5
 Podaj A:2
  KALKULATOR [3]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:6
  HISTORIA
 10. wypisz.
 11. usun.
 12. zapisz do pliku
 13. wyswietl z pliku
 14. usun z pliku
 co chcesz zrobic z historia:10
 2+2=4
2-2=0
2^2=4
 KALKULATOR [3]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:6
  HISTORIA
 10. wypisz.
 11. usun.
 12. zapisz do pliku
 13. wyswietl z pliku
 14. usun z pliku
 co chcesz zrobic z historia:12

3
 KALKULATOR [3]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:1
 Podaj A:2
  Podaj B:2

WYKONUJE SIE
 KALKULATOR [4]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:6
  HISTORIA
 10. wypisz.
 11. usun.
 12. zapisz do pliku
 13. wyswietl z pliku
 14. usun z pliku
 co chcesz zrobic z historia:10
 1309873488▀479=1309868368
2-2=0
2^2=4
1309891696?479=1102239351
 KALKULATOR [4]
 1. dodwanie
 2. odejmowanie
 3. mnozenie
 4. dzielenie
 5. potegowanie
 6. historia
 co chcesz policzyc:
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is the you are not updating your array pointer (dzi in main)

example

```
void dodawanie(int x, int y, struct d* dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x+y;
    dzialania = realloc(dzialania, ok*sizeof(struct d));
    dzialania[ok-1].a = x;
    dzialania[ok-1].b = y;
    dzialania[ok-1].wynik = w;
    dzialania[ok-1].znak = '+';
    printf("\nWYKONUJE SIE\n");
}
```

You have passed dzi by value, any changes you make in this function are private to it. The value of dzi in main is unchanged. SO the next time you call realloc you are pointing to an area that was already realloced.

You need to pass dzi by reference. I have fixed one, you need to fix all.

```
void dodawanie(int x, int y, struct d** dzialania)
{
    ok++;
    int w = x + y;
    *dzialania = realloc(*dzialania, ok * sizeof(struct d));
    struct d* dz = *dzialania;
    dz[ok - 1].a = x;
    dz[ok - 1].b = y;
    dz[ok - 1].wynik = w;
    dz[ok - 1].znak = '+';
    printf("\nWYKONUJE SIE\n");
}

...
...

    dodawanie(A, B, &dzi);
```